# workon not working after install item2 and zsh

Tags: virtualenv, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I previously using virtualenvwrapper and it works fine.

```
workon virtualenvName
```

will works.

However, after I install iterm2, zsh, and oh-my-zsh, and suddenly virtualenvwrapper and workon is not working now. In the terminal, enter

```
~ workon virtualenvName
zsh: command not found: workon
```

When i use iterm2,

```
~ workon virtualenvName
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
```

This time it will open the virtual environment. So my question is 1. how can I run virtual environment again in terminal? 2. Why there is "/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper" in iterm2 but the virtual environment can open up?